# Java field initialization

Tags: java

Suppose I hava a class `B` which have a Class `C` type member as field.

Now I wrote a constructor for `B` so that its default constructor won't be synthesized.

But `B's` constructor doesn't initialize that `C` type field explicitly.

```
Class B
{
  C obj_c;

  B()
  { }
}
```

In C++ default constructor of `obj_c` would be called coz default constructors of non-initialized members would be called implicitly for Object type members.What about Java??

What would happen if a constructor doesn't initialize a field in Java?

Comment: Unless you say `obj_c = new C();`, `C's` constructor won't get called. It will remain `null` until you **initialize** it.

Comment: java initializes the obj_c to `null` in this case..

Comment: Imagine a `*` after every type name in a variable declaration (and `= 0` if absent), and you'll get something approaching C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uninitialized member variables are automatically initialized to `false` for booleans, `0` for numbers, and `null` for object references, which is where `obj_c` falls here.  It gets initialized to `null`.

**EDIT**

It's not the constructor that is initializing it to `null`; according to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), Java will initialize class variables and instance variables if you don't initialize them.

Comment: ok, does 'obj_c' being set to 'null' has any thing to do with constructor. Is obj_c 'null' because constructor sets it to null ??

Answer (score 1):

C's constructor is not called implicitly. It has to be invoked explicitly either through the field initialization or setting from the constructor.